# Binding combobox selecteditem to textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have on combobox with products, one textbox. In text property of textbox I want to bind selected product's price from combobox. To that moment it can be made for example like this:

```
<TextBox Name="txtSalePrice"   InputScope="Digits" Text="{Binding ElementName=cmbProducts, Path=SelectedItem.Price}" />
 <ComboBox x:Name="cmbProducts" ItemsSource="{Binding ListProducts}"  DisplayMemberPath="FullName">
```

Now I want to bind value of textbox to property of some object let's say it's
new sale object 'NewSale' with property 'price', but without change price in selectedProduct.

I have problem with achieve this.

Comment: So you want the price to change based on what you type in the text box?

Comment: `Text="{Binding NewSale}`?

Comment: @chancea: 
1. I choose product from combobox.  
2. Default price from this products is setting in textbox.
3. Now I want for example change this price and bind it to my object 'newSale'

Comment: 1.I choose product from combobox. 
2. Default price from this products is setting in textbox. 
3. Now I want for example change this price and bind it to my object 'newSale'